# ReLU not learning to handle negative inputs Keras / Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, keras

I want my neural network to convert a negative value into a positive value. Theoretically this can be done using a ReLU function and 1 node which learns the input weight to be -1 (so a negative input is multiplied by -1 = positive input.

It just keeps on outputting 0. Code below. I used -1 as input values to see if it could learn on at least a single input.

I tried adding more layers but it doesn't help **see edit, IT DID help if I add more**

```
train_input = np.asarray([[-1]]*10000) # Input arr of -1s
train_output = np.asarray(map(lambda x: [abs(x[0])] , train_input))

# Define the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='linear'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=.001))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train and evaluate
model.fit(train_input, train_output, epochs=10, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
test_model_output = model.predict(test_input)
print str(test_input[0][0]) + " " + str(test_output[0][0]) + " " +  str(test_model_output[0][0])
```

The output I get is below (1st value is input, 2nd is expected output, 3rd is model output )

```
-1 1 0.0
```

**EDIT**
I tried using the random uniform initialiser so it would initialise negative weights and it works. I get why this should make it *easier* for the network to learn. But I don't get why it's necessary.

```
from keras.initializers import RandomUniform
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=1, kernel_initializer=RandomUniform(minval=-0.05, maxval=0.05, seed=None), activation='linear'))
```

**EDIT 2**
Someone mentioned I didn't have enough time to train the data. At first I thought making it 10x more data and batches to be 10x smaller (more iterations) would work. It didn't
**BUT** if I added 10x more epochs (100 total) it did work. So it just takes a long time to convert positive initialised weights to negative

Comment: maybe you just didn't train long enough for the weight to go from 1 to -1 ? Typically here you have (1000/100)*10=100 gradient iterations, if the learning rate is 0.01 (pretty standard) your weights only have time to reach 0

Comment: That would actually explain why you get 0.0, which should not be the case with a leaky relU and weight=1

Comment: I get same results with 10000 data sets and 10 epochs and batch size of 10. I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was not giving it enough time to train. While it's a very basic function the initialised weights have to go form negative to positive.

Increase the amount of training done (more epochs, smaller batches, more training data) eventually caused the gradient to flip from positive to negative.

Answer (score 2):

I would initialise that first weight to be negative using 
keras.initializers.Constant(value=-1) 
https://keras.io/initializers/#constant

May help to get that first neuron firing.

Comment: Tried using a random value initialization ( i thought -1 was cheating :p) and it works to push the gradient to -1.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the libraries you're using, but it seems like you have to speicify the `input_shape` in the `Dense` line.

> where `None` indicates that any positive integer may be expected

So if you input nothing as input_shape, then it assumes your input will be any positive number.

So adding `input_shape=(-1,1)` might fix your problem!

https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/

Comment: Thanks for commenting here too Thomas.
Tried that but got a random error, I'm not sure if -1 is a valid input for a shape (unlike in Tensorflow). 
The problem was just that it needed a lot more training to switch from a positive gradient to a negative one

Answer (score 1):

I think the outcome of the model is correct.

Because​, Rectified Linear Unit works as follows

f(x) = max(0,x) [x - > input to the neuron]

In your example, input value is -1. i.e (x = -1)

f(x) = max(0,-1) => Answer for this equation is Zero ['0']

This may be the reason behind your models' result

(or)

Possibly, error while performing multiplication may occurred.

Comment: if the weight leading to the first neuron is negative, the input will be greater than 0. the solution to the above problem using ReLu is the input weight being -1 and output weight being 1, I believe.

Comment: I used a Leaky ReLU for this reason, so it will output a small negative value if a negative value is fed into it, still allowing for trainig